# ImportError: cannot import name qr_insert

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I run the following import statement:

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
```

and I get the following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_gcrotmk.py", line 10, in <module>
  from scipy.linalg import (get_blas_funcs, qr, solve, svd, qr_insert, lstsq)
ImportError: cannot import name qr_insert
```

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: what if you uninstall scikit and reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

Broken instalaltion. Use:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

and

```
pip install scipy
```

Comment: I just ran "pip install -U scikit-learn" and it still showing me the same error message. When I hover over "resample" I get a warning saying 'resample is not declared in __all__'

Comment: try to install again scipy. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I switched from python 2.7 to a virtual env using python 3.7 and it worked. The `qr_insert` module might not have been supported by python 2.7, but that is an issue in and of itself. Thanks again for the help!